# Is there a more better/efficient way to loop in `cmd.exe` than using `for`?

Tags: windows, command-line, script, cmd.exe

I've successfully used the `for` command with different switches several times in the past but it is usually more trouble than it's worth. It seems to be easier to output to a text file and then use regular expressions to make a simple script, than to test `for` command lines. There seem to be too many hidden potholes where it is likely behave in a way contrary to its purpose: To manipulate files.

Is it the learning curve?
What is a similar substitute?

Comment: I've never had any problem with `FOR`, and I've used it for some pretty complex things. I strongly urge you to read [Microsoft Docs on `FOR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) and [SS64 on `FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) _thoroughly_, including the pages at SS64 for specific usages.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is old and is based on DOS's command prompt, which was itself based on a CP/M command shell from the 8-bit days of computing.  The "command extensions" introduced with Windows NT in the mid 90's were meant to not disturb existing batch files, and they are arcane.  It's much better to put your effort into Powershell for many reasons, the main being Powershell is an actual scripting language and not just a batch file processor with extensions bolted on.

Answer (score 3):

It's more intuitive for creating the text output. Avoid using it to perform potentially destructive tasks. It has some nice tricks if the potholes/warts can be compensated for. Pardon the pun.

Try powershell, it has a for loop that you can use without the syntax baggage of the CMD `for` - just combine it with file manipulation cmdlets in get, set, select and item, location, string families.

Comment: I haven't completely abandoned the use of `CMD`, but I definitely agree that in most cases, PowerShell handles things much betterer [SIC].

Comment: Outside of pre-Win7 compatibility, powershell is only benefits over cmd. There's no other reason I'm aware of to keep using cmd.

Comment: PowerShell has a much steeper learning curve than CMD. In my experience CMD is as dependable but has less gotchas.

Comment: @harrymc Changing one's mindset to think objects is a challenge in pwsh. But having a real language with consistent syntax helps flatten to curve.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some very complicated things with `for`. The cmd shell is powerful but complicated and the learning curve is real.  I switched to PowerShell 10 years ago and haven't looked back except to convert old cmd scripts.